# How to avoid brackets in SQL around Django custom database function call?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

A short intoduction to the problem...

- PostgreSQL has very neat array fields (int array, string array) and functions for them like `UNNEST` and `ANY`.
- These fields are supported by Django (I am using `djorm_pgarray` for that), but functions are not natively supported.
- One could use `.extra()`, but Django 1.8 introduced a new concept of [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/).

Let me provide a most primitive example of what I am basicly doing with all these. A `Dealer` has a list of makes that it supports. A `Vehicle` has a make and is linked to a dealer. But it happens that `Vehicle`'s make does not match `Dealer`'s make list, that is inevitable.

```
MAKE_CHOICES = [('honda', 'Honda'), ...]

class Dealer(models.Model):
    make_list = TextArrayField(choices=MAKE_CHOICES)

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, null=True, blank=True)
    make   = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=MAKE_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

Having a database of dealers and makes, I want to count all vehicles for which the vehicle's make and its dealer's make list do match. That's how I do it avoiding `.extra()`.

```
from django.db.models import functions

class SelectUnnest(functions.Func):
    function = 'SELECT UNNEST'

...

Vehicle.objects.filter(
    make__in=SelectUnnest('dealer__make_list')
).count()
```

Resulting SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "myapp_vehicle" 
INNER JOIN "myapp_dealer" 
  ON ( "myapp_vehicle"."dealer_id" = "myapp_dealer"."id" ) 
WHERE "myapp_vehicle"."make" 
  IN (SELECT UNNEST("myapp_dealer"."make_list"))
```

And it works, and much faster than a traditional M2M approach we could use in Django. BUT, for this task, `UNNEST` is not a very good solution: `ANY` is much faster. Let's try it.

```
class Any(functions.Func):
    function = 'ANY'

...

Vehicle.objects.filter(
    make=Any('dealer__make_list')
).count()
```

It generates the following SQL:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "myapp_vehicle" 
 INNER JOIN "myapp_dealer" 
   ON ( "myapp_vehicle"."dealer_id" = "myapp_dealer"."id" )
 WHERE "myapp_vehicle"."make" = 
  (ANY("myapp_dealer"."make_list"))
```

And it fails, because braces around `ANY` are bogus. If you remove them, it runs in the `psql` console with no problems, and fast.

So my question.

1. Is there any way to remove these braces? I could not find anything about that in Django documentation.
2. If not, - maybe there are other ways to rephrase this query?

**P. S.** I think that an extensive library of database functions for different backends would be very helpful for database-heavy Django apps.

Of course, most of these will not be portable. But you typically do not often migrate such a project from one database backend to another. In our example, using array fields and PostGIS we are stuck to PostgreSQL and do not intend to move.

Is anybody developing such a thing?

**P. P. S.** One might say that, in this case, we should be using a separate table for makes and intarray instead of string array, that is correct and will be done, but nature of problem does not change.

**UPDATE.**

- `TextArrayField` is defined at [djorm_pgarray](https://github.com/niwinz/djorm-pgarray/blob/master/djorm_pgarray/fields.py). At the linked source file, you can see how it works.
- The value is list of text strings. In Python, it is represented as a list. Example: `['honda', 'mazda', 'anything else']`.

Here is what is said about it in the database.

```
=# select id, make from appname_tablename limit 3;
id | make
---+----------------------
58 | {vw}
76 | {lexus,scion,toyota}
39 | {chevrolet}
```

And underlying PostgreSQL field type is `text[]`.

Comment: This is most interesting, I think though it isn't explicitly mentioned in the documentation, Func and it's subclasses can only be used in aggreate and annotate but not in filter.

Comment: I even tried overriding the as_sql method in Func to see if that can be used to strip out the brackets. But it turns out that the brackets are added elsewhere

Comment: @e4c5 yes, I have looked into the source too. Maybe there is someone who is deeply involved with Django ORM internals and can answer that.

Comment: have you tried with template property?

Comment: @jerzyk yes, but it does not help. Template `%(function)s(%(expressions)s)` is responsible for generating `ANY(some_field_name)`, but not the brackets that surround that instruction.

Comment: for the question completness, could you please add TextArrayField definition and what data is stored there (array of strings, array of array of strings, maybe example value)?

Comment: @Jerzyk updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to get (more or less) what you need using following:

```
from django.db.models.lookups import BuiltinLookup
from django.db.models.fields import Field

class Any(BuiltinLookup):
    lookup_name = 'any'

    def get_rhs_op(self, connection, rhs):
       return " = ANY(%s)" % (rhs,)

Field.register_lookup(Any)
```

and query:

```
Vehicle.objects.filter(make__any=F('dealer__make_list')).count()
```

as result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "zz_vehicle"
  INNER JOIN "zz_dealer" ON ("zz_vehicle"."dealer_id" = "zz_dealer"."id")
    WHERE "zz_vehicle"."make"  = ANY(("zz_dealer"."make_list"))
```

btw. instead djorm_pgarray and `TextArrayField` you can use native django:

```
make_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)
```

(to simplify your dependencies)

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not think about custom database lookups at all. We will definitely use this approach. Thank you again, that is VERY cool.